# Two services for the same Pod on GKE

Tags: kubernetes

**Question**

Is it problematic to create two Services for the same pod, one for internal access and the other for external access?

**Context**

I have a simple app running on GKE.

There are two pods, each with one container:

1. flask-pod, which runs a containerized flask app
2. postgres-pod, which runs a containerized postgres DB

The flask app accesses the postgres DB through a ClusterIP Service around the postgres DB.

**Concern**

I also have connected a client app, TablePlus (running on my machine), to the postgres DB through a LoadBalancer Service. Now I have 2 separate services to access my postgres DB. Is this redundant, or can this cause problems?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine. If you look at StatefulSets, you define one headless service that is used for internal purpose and another service to allow access from clients.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is absolutely valid, there is nothing wrong with it. You can create as many Services per Pod as you like.